# y-labels with tikz-fct

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-fct

I have the following code to plot the function r(x) = abs((x-x^3/6-x^5/120+x^7/5040)-sin x) with the package tikz-fct.
The range for y is very small, of order 10^-5.
When I run this code, a y-thicks are very strange, with tikz for example 0.000,05.
How can I modify the apperance of y-labels, for example, using 10^-5 in evidence?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2,yscale=1.5,cap=round]
\tkzInit[xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,xstep=0.5,ymax=0.0001,ystep=0.00005]
\tkzAxeX
\tkzAxeY
\tkzFct[domain=-1.5:1.5,samples=800,draw=blue,thick]{abs(\x - (\x**3)/6 + (\x**5)/120 - (\x**7)/5040 - sin(\x))}
\tkzFct[domain=-1.5:1.5,samples=800,draw=red,thick]{0.00005}

\tkzDefPointByFct[ref=A,with=b](-1.38)
\tkzDefPointByFct[ref=B,with=b](1.38)
\tkzPointShowCoord(B)
\tkzPointShowCoord(A)

\tkzDefPointByFct[with=a](1.5)
\tkzText[above,blue](tkzPointResult){$|r_{7,0}(x)|$}

\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black,size=3](A)
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black,size=3](B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `tikz-fct` but regardless of the package you might want to use a logarithmic plot. With `pgfplots` this could be something like `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log]
\addplot[no marks] {abs((x-x^3/6-x^5/120+x^7/5040)-sin(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

`tkz-fct` is a tool for the french students. `pgfplots` is a very fine tool for university and scientists. You can't ask too much of the first tool. It wants to keep it simple.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2,yscale=1.5,cap=round]
\tkzInit[xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,xstep=0.5,ymax=0.0001,ystep=0.00001]
\tkzAxeX% \tkzAxeY
\tkzDrawY
 \foreach \y in {1,...,9}%
 {\draw[shift={(0,\y)}] node[left=6pt] {$\y.10^{-5}$};}

\tkzFct[domain=-1.5:1.5,samples=800,draw=blue,thick]{abs(\x - (\x**3)/6 + (\x**5)/120 - (\x**7)/5040 - sin(\x))}
\tkzFct[domain=-1.5:1.5,samples=800,draw=red,thick]{0.00005}

\tkzDefPointByFct[ref=A,with=b](-1.38)
\tkzDefPointByFct[ref=B,with=b](1.38)
\tkzPointShowCoord(B)
\tkzPointShowCoord(A)

\tkzDefPointByFct[with=a](1.5)
\tkzText[above,blue](tkzPointResult){$|r_{7,0}(x)|$}

\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black,size=3](A)
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black,size=3](B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Best regards.

Comment: @AngeloAlianoFilho  I uploaded a new version yesterday !